# How to query hundreds of partitions efficiently to get data for graph

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, nosql

In order to improve efficiency in getting per-day totals/averages and show then on a graph I need to change the way I'm querying and probably storing analytics data.

Currently my data is stored in relational db, partitioned to date (per day) and every product that I have has a unique row in each partition.

The following partition table is an example of my raw data

```
|date     |product_id|total_rev|total_orders|
|---------|----------|---------|------------|
|2019-11-1|1         | 1000    | 40         |
|2019-11-1|2         | 2000    | 30         |
```

As for now, each of my partitions includes 2M rows I have more than a year of daily partitions

My issue is when I want to show data per day (or any desired time-frame) per group of products it I have to go to these partitions and pull daily data. For short period it's ok (up to 7 days) but for longer period it takes too long.

What's the best approach to deal with this problem ?

I'm thinking about doing ETL to mongo-db and store documents per product and have a key per day.
Then query with product ids and specific date range to get a collection of desired data

I'd like to get a professional opinion on that and various alternatives.

Comment: If your query takes too long, your first step should be to make it faster, not to hopscotch from product to product.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info for how to ask effective performance questions.  Are you using declarative partitioning, inheritance partitioning, or some home-grown partitioning method?

Comment: @jjanes I'm using inheritance partitioning. My query is pretty effective but the size of each partition (per day) is big enough and creates slowness as it needs to fetch data from many large partitions.